# Further explain NSManagedObject's delete rule Nullify

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Here's Apple's documentation for the Nullify delete rule:

> **Nullify** Set the inverse relationship for objects at the destination to null. For example, if you delete a department, set the
>   department for all the current members to null. This only makes sense
>   if the department relationship for an employee is optional, or if you
>   ensure that you set a new department for each of the employees before
>   the next save operation.

Using this department <-------->> employee example, the department's employees are represented by an NSSet. If I delete an employee and the delete rule is set to Nullify, what happens to the NSSet? Is the deleted employee object removed from the set? Does the reference to that employee in the set become nil? Does the whole set get nullified?

Also, in this scenario, does anything else need to be done in code in order to maintain referential integrity?

Comment: Your error handling is wrong. You need to test the return value of `-save:`, not test if `error` is non-`nil`.

Comment: Ok, updated that, but it has no effect on the code's behavior. Do you see anything that would be causing the above mentioned behavior?

Comment: Offhand, no. Have you tried refreshing the company after the save?

Comment: I figured out the issue. In the end, it had nothing to do with the delete rules. It ended up being an issue with using multiple managed object contexts and merging issues. I'm deleting the code section of the question since it is not really relevant to the Q & A at this point. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your many-to-one example, the employee is removed from the `NSSet`. The "set to nil" explanation is what happens with a one-to-one relationship.

This is in contrast with the "No Action" rule, which literally does nothing (and you probably shouldn't use), the "Deny" rule, which prevents the deletion if the relationship isn't already nilled out, and the "Cascade" rule, which deletes the destination object(s) as well.

Comment: When I use Nullify in this scenario, I end up crashing. Right now I am using No Action and in my NSManagedObjectContext I am first removing the employee from the company's NSSet, then deleting the employee and saving my NSManagedObjectContext. Do I need to change the way I am performing the delete in order for Nullify to work properly?

Comment: @JeremyZ: Use Nullify, and don't bother removing the employee from the company's `NSSet`. That should work. If that crashes, you may have something weird going on. What's the crash?

Comment: Sorry, there is no crash... the data just doesn't change after the save. See the code I added to my question above.